# submit form data to serverside

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
<form ng-submit="doRegister()">
    <div class="control-group">
        <label for="email">E-Mail Address</label>
        <input type="email" id="email" name="email" ng-model="user.email" autofocus>
    </div>
    <div class="control-group">
        <label for="password">Password</label>
        <input type="password" id="password" name="user.password" ng-model="password">
    </div>
    <div class="control-group">
        <label for="password_confirmation">Confirm Password</label>
        <input type="password" id="password_confirmation" name="password_confirmation" ng-model="user.password_confirmation">
    </div>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

How do I submit the form to `register` via `POST`? Technically I don't know where `data` could be placed.

```
function registerCtrl ($scope, $http) {
    document.title = 'Register';
    $scope.doRegister = function(){
        $http.post('/register', data).
            success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                console.log(data);
            }).
            error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                angular.element('.errors').html(data.errors.join('<br>')).slideDown();
            });
    };
}
```

**EDIT**: Progress:

```
function registerCtrl ($scope, $http) {
    document.title = 'Register';
    $scope.user = {};
    $scope.doRegister = function(){
        $http.post('/register', $scope.user);
    };
}
```

but the request sent to the server was an empty array in [php](/questions/tagged/php):

```
Array()
```

Comment: What does the browser say is being sent?  Have a look in the debug console / network tab.

Answer (score 1):

You already have a properties binded within the form.
You can define data using them.

For example, for email field:

```
var data = {};
data.email = $scope.email;
```

Or you can even define `$scope.data = {}` in controller,
and post it.

---

### EDIT on 9/14

This seems to be one of the problem that people see with $http.post() for sending
form data.  Solution is given in the following Q&A.

[AngularJS - Any way for $http.post to send request parameters instead of JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12190166/angularjs-any-way-for-http-post-to-send-request-parameters-instead-of-json)

Comment: but when I dump the request on the server I only see an empty array.

Comment: You may want to add: `$http.defaults.headers.post['Content-Type'] = 'application/x-www-form-url';` also transform needed.  Otherwise, it'll be url encoded. see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12190166/angularjs-any-way-for-http-post-to-send-request-parameters-instead-of-json

Comment: @toshshimayama You may want to update your answer with the info in your comment. I suspect the server side isn't expecting JSON, and so the data needs to be transformed to send up name-value paired request parameters.

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare variables and change `headers` like this:

```
function registerCtrl ($scope, $http) {
    document.title = 'Register';
    $scope.user = {
        email: '',
        password: ''
    };
    $scope.doRegister = function(){
        $http({
            url: '/register', 
            data: $scope.user,
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
            transformRequest: function(obj) {
                var str = [];
                for(var p in obj)
                    str.push(encodeURIComponent(p) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(obj[p]));
                return str.join("&");
            },
        });
    };
}
```

And you need

Answer (score 0):

AngularJS' post method sends data as Request Payload.

Just use:

```
$json = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
```

You can access values in php by using

```
$email = $json->email;
$password = $json->password;
$password_confirmation = $json->password_confirmation;
```

Answer (score -2):

```
<form id="Register" action="/register">
 <div class="control-group">
        <label for="email">E-Mail Address</label>
        <input type="email" id="email" name="email" ng-model="email" autofocus>
    </div>
    <div class="control-group">
        <label for="password">Password</label>
        <input type="password" id="password" name="password" ng-model="password">
    </div>
    <div class="control-group">
        <label for="password_confirmation">Confirm Password</label>
        <input type="password" id="password_confirmation" name="password_confirmation" ng-model="password_confirmation">
    </div>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

call ajax function.

```
$.ajax({
    url: form.prop('action'),
    type: 'POST',
    data: form.serialize(),
    dataType: 'json',
    async: false,
    success: function (result) {

    }
}); // ajax post end
```

`var form = $("#Register");`
data pass `form.serialize()` that is very easy to pass data from server side.

Comment: what if I don't want to use jQuery?

Comment: `function registerCtrl ($scope, $http,$form) {}` add one argument to pass form data as `var form = $("#Register")`