# How to add call back for $resource methods in AngularJS

Tags: resources, callback, angularjs

It could be a  common case that we need to show an error/success message to the user after he updates/creates some data, how can we implement it in AngularJS?
I want to add callbacks but could not find a solution. Using $http.post().success().error() works, but I wonder if I can do it with the higher lever API $resource.
Or, we should write directives or use $watch()?
Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Actions from the **Resource** class can be passed success and error callbacks just like the lower level **$http** service

[From the docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource)

- HTTP GET "class" actions: Resource.action([parameters], [success], [error])
- non-GET "class" actions: Resource.action([parameters], postData, [success], [error])

Non-get actions are prefixed with `$`.

So you can do this

```
User.get({userId:123}, function(u, getResponseHeaders){
  // this is get's success callback
  u.abc = true;
  u.$save(function(u, putResponseHeaders) {
    // This is $save's success callback, invoke notification from here
  });
});
```

---

Edit: here's [another example from a previous plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/gV2zwc2kKAXXESe9HME4?p=preview). The get request will fail since it request a non existing json file. The error callback will be run.

```
someResource.get(function(data){
    console.log('success, got data: ', data);       
}, function(err){
    alert('request failed');
});
```

Comment: Many thanks! The further question is how to wrap the data into form data? the solution in [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12190166/angularjs-any-way-for-http-post-to-send-request-parameters-instead-of-json) seems does not work for Resource methods(can work for $http.put). thanks

Comment: comment = Comment.save($scope.newComment, (response) -> console.log("Comment submitted.")) ...works too.

Comment: The format for non-get actions is Resource.action([parameters], postData, [success], [error]) .. But in your example it is different u.$save(function(u, putResponseHeaders) {...........

Answer (score 5):

With latest AngularJS versions, you could have a look to the [`$interceptors`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#interceptors) which are part of the `$httpProvider`.

Then you can intercept ALL the requests before beeing sent or after the response.

```
angular.module('app').config(function($httpProvider){

  $httpProvider.interceptors.push(function($q) {
    return {
      'request': function(config) {
        console.log('I will send a request to the server');
        return config; 
      },

      'response': function(response) {
        // called if HTTP CODE = 2xx 
        console.log('I got a sucessfull response from server'); 
        return response;
      }

      'responseError': function(rejection) {
        // called if HTTP CODE != 2xx
        console.log('I got an error from server');
        return $q.reject(rejection);
      }
    };
  });

});
```

Note that you have to return `config` or `response` to get it working.

In the case of `rejection`, you need to return a deferred rejection, to get the `$http.get().error()` still working after the interception.