# AngularJs: Have method return synchronously when it calls $http or $resource internally

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Is there a way to wait on a promise so that you can get the actual result from it and return that instead of returning the promise itself?  I'm thinking of something similar to how the C# await keyword works with Tasks.

Here is an example of why I'd like to have a method like canAccess() that returns true or false instead of a promise so that it can be used in an if statement.  The method canAccess() would make an AJAX call using $http or $resource and then somehow wait for the promise to get resolved.

The would look something like this:

```
$scope.canAccess = function(page) {
    var resource = $resource('/api/access/:page');
    var result = resource.get({page: page});

    // how to await this and not return the promise but the real value
    return result.canAccess;
}
```

Is there anyway to do this?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

In general that's a bad idea. Let me tell you why. JavaScript in a browser is basically a single threaded beast. Come to think of it, it's single threaded in Node.js too. So anything you do to not "return" at the point you start waiting for the remote request to succeed or fail will likely involve some sort of looping to delay execution of the code after the request. Something like this:

```
var semaphore = false;
var superImportantInfo = null;

// Make a remote request.
$http.get('some wonderful URL for a service').then(function (results) {
  superImportantInfo = results;

  semaphore = true;
});

while (!semaphore) {
  // We're just waiting.
}

// Code we're trying to avoid running until we know the results of the URL call.
console.log('The thing I want for lunch is... " + superImportantInfo);
```

But if you try that in a browser and the call takes a long time, the browser will think your JavaScript code is stuck in a loop and pop up a message in the user's face giving the user the chance to stop your code. JavaScript therefore structures it like so:

```
// Make a remote request.
$http.get('some wonderful URL for a service').then(function (results) {
  // Code we're trying to avoid running until we know the results of the URL call.
  console.log('The thing I want for lunch is... " + results);
});

// Continue on with other code which does not need the super important info or 
// simply end our JavaScript altogether. The code inside the callback will be 
// executed later.
```

The idea being that the code in the callback will be triggered by an event whenever the service call returns. Because event driven is how JavaScript likes it. Timers in JavaScript are events, user actions are events, HTTP/HTTPS calls to send and receive data generate events too. And you're expected to structure your code to respond to those events when they come.

Can you not structure your code such that it thinks canAccess is false until such time as the remote service call returns and it maybe finds out that it really is true after all? I do that all the time in AngularJS code where I don't know what the ultimate set of permissions I should show to the user is because I haven't received them yet or I haven't received all of the data to display in the page at first. I have defaults which show until the real data comes back and then the page adjusts to its new form based on the new data. The two way binding of AngularJS makes that really quite easy.

Comment: Yeah you make some very good points.  I can definitely structure my code that way and it shouldn't be too difficult.  I was more curious if there was a way to do it, but you've talked me out of the usefullness of that.  I like the idea of defaulting to no access and then letting the two way binding take care of the rest.  Thanks.

Comment: In the first example, I don't think that the condition for the `while` statement will ever be truthy. This is because it will run synchronously and block the HTTP request from ever happening.

Comment: In some cases you really want to wait, I think that was the original question. This answer does not really answer that.

Comment: Even though I agree with the points made in the answer, I don't like the "You shouldn't even be doing that, do something else" answers because they don't answer the question. Answer the question!

Comment: Thanks! sometimes you really have to wait (in my case i need data from Angular inside a jQuery Plugin ..)

Comment: @mightyiam already suggested this, and in my application I found him to be right. The while loop blocks the application and never breaks.

Answer (score 2):

Use a .get() callback function to ensure you get a resolved resource.

Helpful links:

- [Official docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource.$resource)
- [How to add call back for $resource methods in AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13852444/how-to-add-call-back-for-resource-methods-in-angularjs)

Answer (score 1):

**You can't** - there aren't any features in [angular](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q), [Q](https://github.com/kriskowal/q) (promises) or javascript (at this point in time) that let do that.

**You will** when [ES7](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q) happens (with [await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await)).

**You can** if you use another framework or a transpiler (as suggested in the article linked - Traceur transpiler or Spawn).

You can if you roll your own implementation!

Answer (score 0):

My approach was create a function with OLD javascript objects  as follows:

```
var globalRequestSync = function (pUrl, pVerbo, pCallBack) {

        httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
        httpRequest.onreadystatechange = function () {

            if (httpRequest.readyState == 4 && httpRequest.status == 200) {
                pCallBack(httpRequest.responseText);
            }
        }
        httpRequest.open(pVerbo, pUrl, false);
        httpRequest.send(null);

    };
```

Answer (score 0):

I recently had this problem and made a utility called 'syncPromises'. This basically works by sending what I called an "instruction list", which would be array of functions to be called in order. You'll need to call the first then() to kick things of, dynamically attach a new .then() when the response comes back with the next item in the instruction list so you'll need to keep track of the index.

```js
// instructionList is array.
function syncPromises (instructionList) {
  var i = 0,
    defer = $q.defer();

  function next(i) {

    // Each function in the instructionList needs to return a promise
    instructionList[i].then(function () {
      var test = instructionList[i++];
      if(test) {
        next(i);
      }
    });
  }

  next(i);

  return defer.promise;
}
```

This I found gave us the most flexibility.
You can automatically push operations etc to build an instruction list and you're also able to append as many .then() responses handlers in the callee function. You can also chain multiple syncPromises functions that will all happen in order.