# Can I have, using AngularJS ($http), the following call sequence?

Tags: angularjs, http, call, sequence

```
testAngular();  //**(1º)**

function testAngular() {

        var uri = 'some_webmethod_url';

        var data = {
            "key": "anything"
        };

        var res = $http.post(uri, data);

        res.then(function (data) {

            console.log(data); //**(2º)**

        });

        console.log(data); //**(3º)**
}

console.log(data);  //**(4º)**
```

The actual sequence is  **1º -- 3º -- 4º -- 2º**; Why?
And more importantly, **how can I make this in that sequence? (1º -- 2º -- 3º -- 4º)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the 'then' is a callback and called asynchronously when the response from the server becomes available (after the POST request is completed). So the statement `console.log(data); //**(2º)**` will be executed only after the response is received but rest of other processing will continue.

If you want the order that you mentioned, you will have to make those statement as part of the callback. The other option is to make the callbacks synchronous which is not supported out of the box by Angular JS but you can look into the source code and make changes. This SO post might help you in that [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13088153/how-to-http-synchronous-call-with-angularjs](http://How%20to%20$http%20Synchronous%20call%20with%20AngularJS)

Or a small hack as mentioned in other SO post might help you [AngularJs: Have method return synchronously when it calls $http or $resource internally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20184070/angularjs-have-method-return-synchronously-when-it-calls-http-or-resource-int) though it's not recommended.

```
testAngular();  //**(1º)**

    function testAngular() {

            var uri = 'some_webmethod_url';

            var data = {
                "key": "anything"
            };

            var res = $http.post(uri, data);

            res.then(function (data) {

                console.log(data); //**(2º)**

                console.log(data); //**(3º)**
                console.log(data);  //**(4º)**
            });


    }
```