# Make the browser wait for api response / http call response in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, http, q

I tried the `$q` service as follows but the browser still not waiting for the response. I already spent almost a day to figure out a solution, I also tried the `$timeout`.

```
login.controller("loginCtrl", ['$scope', '$rootScope', '$filter',   '$window', '$http', 'APIService', 'localStorageService', 'doAlert', '$translate', '$q', '$timeout',

  function ($scope, $rootScope, $filter, $window, $http, APIService, localStorageService, doAlert, $translate, $q, $timeout) {
    $scope.isLogOut = true;

    $(window).unload(function () {
        $rootScope.$broadcast('onUnload');
    });
    $scope.$on('onUnload', function (e) {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        $http.get(url).
                success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                    deferred.resolve(data);
                }).
                error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                    deferred.reject(status);
                });
        return deferred.promise;
    });
```

Comment: Just sayin: `$http`already returns a promise. So there shouldn't be a need of `$q`.

Comment: tried this also . But no luck $http.get(url).success(function(response){
               response.data;
           });

Comment: Use `$http.then(function(success) { ... }, function(error) { ... })` instead of success and error. You may also take a look at the docs: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

Comment: Even with this code, browser does not wait for the response, before it closes.

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20184070/angularjs-have-method-return-synchronously-when-it-calls-http-or-resource-int

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample where I use a callback to process data back from my utility

```
function get(url, callback, obj) {
    $http.get(url, obj)
    .then(function (response) {
        callback(response.data);
    }, function () {
        notification.error(PLEASE_CONTACT_SYS_ADMIN);
    });
}
```

Comment: I am getting angular.min.js:81 ReferenceError: callback is not defined. Can you please elaborate a little bit with my Angular $scope.$on('onUnload') event handler. Kind of new to this.