# Callback for $save method in AngularJS

Tags: node.js, angularjs, recaptcha

I am looking for a callback to use in my `$save` method in angularjs.

I am sending a blog post to the node.js backend, passing it through the recaptcha verifying.

Doing as in the `$resource` documentation is not working:

**non-GET instance actions: instance.$action([parameters], [success], [error])**

```
var post = new Posts({
            title: this.title,
            content: this.content,
            response: this.model.captcha.response,
            challenge: this.model.captcha.challenge
         });

post.$save({}, 
     function(addedpost) {
         $location.path('posts/' + addedpost._id);
    }, function(error) {
         console.log(error);
         vcRecaptchaService.reload();
    });
```

In the server I am using the `simple_recaptcha` module for node.js to verify the recaptcha challenge and response that is packed within the request.

```
var verifyRecaptcha = function(req,res,next){
    var privateKey = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';
    var ip = req.ip;
    var challenge = req.body.challenge;
    var response = req.body.response;
    simple_recaptcha(privateKey, ip, challenge, response, function(err) {
        if(err) return res.send(401,err.message);
        console.log('Recaptcha verified!');
    });
    next();
};
```

So when the captcha is correct it should continue and add the post to the db, if not, the backend responds `401` and the frontend angular js should recognise this as error and refresh the recaptcha.

What am I missing?

Comment: What do you see in the browser debugging tools network tab, should narrow down if this is an issue on the Angular side or the Node side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes I get lost as well in the (normally very good) documentation of AngularJS.
In my case, I found a solution here: [how-to-add-call-back-for-resource-methods-in-angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13852444/how-to-add-call-back-for-resource-methods-in-angularjs)

You can let the server do its work on the POST and analyse the response, something like:

```
    post.$save(
        function(data){
            console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
            if(data.error_message){
                 // ... error_message comes from the server
            } else {
                // ...
            }
        }
    );
```