# AngularJS - Using jQuery param to format resource GET verb query string

Tags: angularjs, angular-resource

I have a backend that understands query strings in the format jQuery's `$.param` returns. For instance, having an object like

```
{ search: "Miller", name: ["Felipe", "Fernanda"] }
```

Will request the URL with the following query string:

```
http://theurl/path?search=Miller&name%5B%5D=Felipe&name%5B%5D=Fernanda
```

Basically it uses `name[]=Felipe&name[]=Fernada`, but URL encoded.

The same object, when parsed by AngularJS ends up with this format:

```
http://theurl/path?search=Miller&name=Felipe,Fernanda
```

Which my backend doesn't understand.

Reading [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12190166/angularjs-any-way-for-http-post-to-send-request-parameters-instead-of-json), I thought that using transformRequest would help, however it doesn't. Here's my testing code:

**HTML**

```
<div ng-controller="UserCtrl">
    <pre>{{ data | json}}</pre>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',['ngResource']);

var transformFn = function(data, headersGetter) {
    console.debug('transformRequest', data);
    if (!data) return;
    console.debug('data in', data);
    var dataOut = $.param(data);
    console.debug('data out', dataOut);
    return dataOut;
};

myApp.config(['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.defaults.transformRequest.push(transformFn);
}]);

myApp.factory('User', ['$resource', function($resource) {
    return $resource('/echo/:type/', {type:'json'}, {
        query: { method: 'GET' }
    });
}]);

myApp.controller('UserCtrl', ['$scope', 'User', function($scope, User) {
    User.query({ seach: 'Miller', name: ['Felipe', 'Fernanda']}, 
       function(data) {
           console.debug('data', data);
           $scope.data = data;
       });
}]);
```

​However, when you try to run this code, you will notice that the data attribute on `transformFn` is always undefined, and the query string stays in the AngularJS format.

You can see this live in jsFiddle too: http://jsfiddle.net/fcoury/QKmnX/

Any idea how I force the query string to use jQuery's $.param format?

**EDIT**: I was checking AngularJS code for branch v1.0.x and I couldn't find any way to change the Query String construction code, that takes place here:

https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.0.x/src/ngResource/resource.js#L299-L306

Does anyone have any clever way to override that part of the ngResource class?

Comment: Nice question. I think you could take Ivo's suggestion and put it here as an answer.

Comment: @Ramunas where is ivo's suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

My simple solution:

```
module.run(['$http', '$httpParamSerializerJQLike', function($http, $httpParamSerializerJQLike) {
  $http.defaults.paramSerializer = $httpParamSerializerJQLike;
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using push? The examples from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12191613/1916258) just assign:

```
$httpProvider.defaults.transformRequest = function(data) {...};
```

Comment: I tried both ways, it doesn't work, data is used for the POST (or PUT) data payload, not for query strings. I am checking AngularJS code and I think it's not possible to override how the query string is created.

Comment: Hmm, just saw that I provided a link to an answer to your other question. Sorry about that. Can't you just use $hhtp instead of $resource?

Comment: Yes, I will be using $http for the time being, but would be nice to have this flexibility, I am proposing it here: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/angular/sXBeosUvSao