# Send Request Body on $resource

Tags: angularjs, angular-resource

I take a look on [Angular API](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource.$resource) for $resource and I didn't find some way to send a `Request Body` to a RESTful service.

I know this is possible using $http approach, like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12190166/angularjs-any-way-for-http-post-to-send-request-parameters-instead-of-json), so, is it also possible to do using `$resource`?

Apparently this is the options for `$resource`.

> **action** – {string} – The name of action. This name becomes the name of the method on your resource object.
>
> **method** – {string} – HTTP request
>   method. Valid methods are: GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, and JSONP
>
> **params** –
>   {object=} – Optional set of pre-bound parameters for this action.
>
> **isArray** – {boolean=} – If true then the returned object for this
>   action is an array, see returns section.

At the moment I didn't found any way to send a request payload containing an JSON object.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

As long as the action supports a body message (e.g. POST, but not GET), you can pass a data parameter to the action method of your resource, which will be sent in the body of the request:

```
yourResource.save(yourData)
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/N3NXK/1/

Comment: Thanks! I was thinking that only parameters inside the {} are acceptable.

Comment: This saved me as well....I'm working with ServiceStack trying to POST ($resource.save()) a complex object which $resource serialized to query string parms which works fine for SS to deserialize flat objects but clearly not complex ones.  Your fiddle saved me!!

Comment: I'm really confused by the jsFiddle you posted. If I look at chrome debugger, the invoked method is a GET over the wire. Doesn't angular make that a POST by default for save?

Comment: @KenPerkins I see a POST first and then a GET. It seems that jsFiddle responds with a 301 to the dummy POST request.

Comment: I think you're right. Chrome Inspector appears to be masking the initial POST :S

Answer (score 41):

Building on `@gargc`'s answer, you can pass parameters and a body to a resource's method:

```
myResource.save({ param: myParam }, myObject);
```