# simple Angular POST request with resource

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-resource

I need to send a simple post request with resource in Angular v-1.
this request must has a body like bottom:

`{name: "mike", code: "1234"}`

```
$scope.pmbusInfo = $resource('http://there.com:8080/api/v1/user/detail',
  null,
  {get: {method: 'POST'}}
);

console.log($scope.pmbusInfo.get({}, {name: "mike", code: "1234"}));
```

but the top codes, can't send body.

what's the problem?

**Update**

what is `save` function, is it a built-in function for resource ???

**Update**

The first adderss was wrong and i modify that now, there was an special port that i have to request to it.

Comment: What error message did you get?

Comment: And why not use $http directly for making requests to a server? Far more easy it is.

Comment: there is no error message, because the request send successfully, but the `POST body` doesn't send.

Comment: @ramsing-nadeem just i want to use resource.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Send Request Body on $resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16203646/send-request-body-on-resource)

Comment: Try $scope.pmbusInfo.get({}, {name: "mike", code: "1234"}).then(function(response){  console.log(response.data) });

Comment: promise isn't support by angular-resource v-1

Comment: @MohammadRaha actually it is via the `$promise` property

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The url in resource requests can contain parameters. we can set parameters with `:` in url.
At the other side, the port separated in the url via a `:` and angular think that is a parameters and clear it when wanna to send request.

so port must write in url like `http://there.com\\:8080/api/v1/user/detail`.

Answer (score 1):

```
$scope.pmbusInfo = $resource('http://there.com/api/v1/user/detail',
  null,  {'save': {method: 'POST'}}
);

console.log($scope.pmbusInfo.save({name: "mike", code: "1234"},function(resp){console.log(resp);}));
```

Comment: `{save: {method: 'POST'}}` is a default action; you don't need to define it at all

Comment: there is no progress

Comment: No error message? What is displayed in network tabs of browser console?

Comment: every thing is right, but the body doesn't send with the request at all.

Comment: How did u conclude that body is not getting sent? If you use chrome, under Network tab click on the api, then on the pane opened, click on headers tab. Now scroll down to see if you can find "Request Headers"

Comment: yes i do this too and there is no body there right now

Comment: there may be 2 calls displayed in console.
1. options                       2. post
is options completed?

Comment: just the first log displayed in the console

Comment: Ok only when 1st is complete 2nd will be called . Are u getting 200 status for 1st? It won't have body

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152633/discussion-between-sreehari-s-and-mohammad-raha).