# angularJs $http. cannot revice params from request

Tags: angularjs

angularjs code:

```
$http({
    method: 'POST',
    url:'/hello/rest/user/test',
    data: {user: 'aaaaa'}
});
```

Server code:

```
@POST
@Path("/test")
public Response merge(@Context HttpServletRequest request) {
    System.out.println(request.getParameter("user"));
    if (request.getParameter("user") == null) {
        return Response.status(Status.BAD_REQUEST).build();
    }
    return Response.ok().build();
}
```

request.getParameter("user") is a null. I cannot revice a parameter by this way.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use request parameter, you need to pass the data as

```
$http.post('/hello/rest/user/test', {
    user : 'aaaaa'
    }, {
        headers : {
            "Content-Type" : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8'
        },
        transformRequest : [function(data) {
            return angular.isObject(data)
                    ? jQuery.param(data)
                    : data;
        }]
    });
```

Also read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12190166/angularjs-any-way-for-http-post-to-send-request-parameters-instead-of-json)

Comment: application/x-www-form-urlencoded, form. But I just want to use 'application/json'. I don't want to use 'form'.

Comment: if you want to sent data as request body ie json then you cannot use `request.getParameter()`. You need to use `@RequestBody` annotation along with jackson library to access the deserialized request

Answer (score 0):

You need to look at the body rather than for the post parameter...

You may not be receiving POST parameters.

You are receiving a body that looks like this {"user":"aaaaa"} and you need to parse that JSON response.