# CRUD operations using AngularJS and Mongoid fail partly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, mongodb, mongoid

I am trying to integrate AngularJS into my Mongoid-powered Rails application. In particular, I want the get the basic CRUD operations to work.

1) Saving a book works!

2) Editing fails: Error: `[$resource:badcfg] Error in resource configuration. Expected response to contain an object but got an array`

3) Deleting fails: `DELETE http://localhost:3000/books 404 (Not Found)`

I suspect that these errors are Mongoid specific as I have tried the exact same code with SQlite and ActiveRecord without any issues. The problems arise with Mongoid and in particular for CRUD operations that are applied on a single record/document. Any suggestions on what's wrong?

**books_ctrl.js.coffee**

```
myApp.factory "Book", ($resource) ->
  $resource("/books/:id", {id: "@id"}, {update: {method: "PUT"}})

myApp.controller "BooksCtrl", ($scope, Book) ->
  $scope.getBooks = () ->
    Book.query().$promise.then (books) ->
      $scope.books = books

  $scope.edit = (book) ->
    $scope.book = Book.get({id: book.id})

  $scope.delete = (book) ->
    book.$delete ->
      $scope.getBooks()

  $scope.save = () ->
    if $scope.book.id?
      Book.update($scope.book).$promise.then ->
        $scope.getBooks()
    else
      Book.save($scope.book).$promise.then ->
        $scope.getBooks()
    $scope.book = {}
```

**books_controller.rb**

```
class BooksController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_book, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /books
  def index
    @books = Book.all

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html {}
      format.json {render json: @books, root: false}
    end
  end

  # GET /books/1
  def show
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html {}
      format.json {render json: @book, root: false}
    end
  end

  # GET /books/new
  def new
    @book = Book.new
  end

  # GET /books/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /books
  def create
    @book = Book.new(book_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @book.save
        format.html {render redirect_to @book, notice: 'Book was successfully created.'}
        format.json {render json: @book}
      else
        format.html {render action: 'new'}
        format.json {render json: @book.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity}
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /books/1
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @book.update(book_params)
        format.html {redirect_to @book, notice: 'Book was successfully updated.'}
        format.json {render json: @book}
      else
        format.html {render action: 'edit'}
        format.json {render json: @book.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity}
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /books/1
  def destroy
    @book.destroy

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html {redirect_to books_url, notice: 'Book was successfully destroyed.'}
      format.json {render json: {message: "Book was deleted."}}
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_book
      @book = Book.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Only allow a trusted parameter "white list" through.
    def book_params
      params.require(:book).permit(:title, :author)
    end
end
```

**books\index.html.erb**

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="BooksCtrl" ng-init="getBooks()">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="span12">
        <form ng-submit="save()">

          <div class="form-group">
            <label>Author</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control span12" ng-model="book.author"/>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group">
            <label>Title</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control span12" ng-model="book.title"/>
          </div>

          <button class="btn btn-success">
            Save
          </button>
        </form>

        <hr />

        <ul>
          <li ng-repeat="book in books">
            <div class="btn-group">
              <div class="btn btn-mini btn-danger" ng-click="delete(book)">
                <i class="icon-trash"></i>
              </div>

              <div class="btn btn-mini btn-default" ng-click="edit(book)">
                <i class="icon-edit"></i>
              </div>
            </div>
            {{$index + 1}} {{book.title}} by {{book.author }}
            </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to stem from Mongoid's serializing behaviour. I followed the instructions and overwrote Mongoid's serializing behaviour as suggested.

[Mongodb + AngularJS: _id empty in update via resourceProvider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22520393/mongodb-angularjs-id-empty-in-update-via-resourceprovider)

Fixed my problem for now. If someone can clarify and provide a more thorough explanation on what the issue is and why it has to be done I would certainly accept that as the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

For your update problems, try to modify this in `book_ctrl.js.coffee` :

```
 $resource("/books/:id", {id: "@id"}, {update: {method: "PUT", isArray: true}})
```

AngularJS needs to know if your API is going to return an array or not. The problem in your API code can be solved with:

`format.json {render json: [@book]}`

Because in cases of errors it seems to me that you return an array. You need to return consistent data for all cases.

Comment: I am trying to delete a single book instance. It seems I have solved the problem using a suggestion from another post. I am editing my answer, posting it soon. Thanks

Comment: I tested your answer and the following happens:
a) Delete works b) Save works c) Editing shows errors! Only after refreshing the page the edits become visible. (Error: Error: [$resource:badcfg] Error in resource configuration. Expected response to contain an array but got an object) Do you know whether I have to adjust anything else? P.S. the other solution works for a), b) and c)