# Set defaults header on AngularJS but don't use it on one specific request

Tags: angularjs, http-headers, request

For sending OAuth2 token I am setting up defaults header on AngularJS like this:

```
$http.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Bearer ' + access_token;
```

This works great but I don't need this header (I get an error) for one specific request.

Is there a way of excluding defaults header when performing that request?

Thanks!

## SOLVED

Thanks to [Riron](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2703657/riron) for getting me on a right path. Here's the answer:

```
$http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'http://.../',

    transformRequest: function(data, headersGetter) {
        var headers = headersGetter();

        delete headers['Authorization'];

        return headers;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

When you make your call with $http, you can override defaults headers by providing them directly in your request config:

```
$http({method: 'GET', url: '/someUrl', headers: {'Authorization' : 'NewValue'} }).success();
```

Otherwise you could transform your request using the `transformRequest` parameter, still in your $http config. See doc :

> transformRequest – `{function(data,headersGetter)|Array.<function(data, headersGetter)>}` – transform
>   function or an array of such functions. The transform function takes
>   the http request body and headers and returns its transformed
>   (typically serialized) version.

This way you could delete an header for a single request before it's being send:

```
$http({method: 'GET', 
       url: '/someUrl', 
       transformRequest: function(data,headersGetter){ //Headers change here } 
}).success();
```

Comment: So if I set it as defaults header (not as transformRequest, but the way I did in my question post), I can't really unset it for one request?

Comment: If you want to unset it, you will have to use the `transformRequest` param for your specific request and modify the headers through a custom function.

Comment: Caution  -  https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/5da1256fc2812d5b28fb0af0de81256054856369        Due to 5da1256, transformRequest functions can no longer modify request headers.

Answer (score 9):

For latecomers, whilst the solution might have worked - you actually shouldn't need to use transformRequest for this.

The Angular docs for the $http service actually have this exact situation covered:

> To explicitly remove a header automatically added via
>   $httpProvider.defaults.headers on a per request basis, Use the headers
>   property, setting the desired header to **undefined**. 
>   For example:

```
 var req = {  
      method: 'POST',  
      url: 'http://example.com',  
      headers: {  
           'Content-Type': undefined  
      },  
      data: { 
           test: 'test' 
      } 
 }

 $http(req).success(function(){...}).error(function(){...});
```

Answer (score 6):

[Angular 1.4.0](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/migration#migrating-from-1-3-to-1-4) can no longer modify request headers using `transformRequest`:

> If one needs to dynamically add / remove headers it should be done in
>   a header function, for example:

```
$http.get(url, {
  headers: {
    'X-MY_HEADER': function(config) {
      return 'abcd'; //you've got access to a request config object to specify header value dynamically
    }
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

While the `$httpProvider` can override `$http`  the use of `intereceptors` are 1 way of handling this,  I end up doing it this way

```
function getMyStuff(blah) {

        var req = {
            method: 'GET',
            url: 'http://...',
            headers: {
                'Authorization': undefined
            }
        }
        return $http(req)
            .then(function(response) {
                return response.data;
            });


}
```