# send request without adding header in angular js

Tags: angularjs, http-headers, request

i'm trying to sending request to third party service. for that i need to delete default header 'x-access-token'. For that did like below

```
$http({
    url: 'http://ip-api.com/json',
    method: 'GET',
    transformRequest: function(data, headersGetter) {
          var headers = headersGetter();

          delete headers['x-access-token'];

          return headers;
        }
  }).then(function(res){
    console.log(res);
  },function(error){
    console.log(error);
  });
```

By following this   [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23696202/set-defaults-header-on-angularjs-but-dont-use-it-on-one-specific-request) .

But i'm getting this error

```
TypeError: Cannot convert object to primitive value
at angular.js:10514
at sendReq (angular.js:10333)
at $get.serverRequest (angular.js:10045)
at processQueue (angular.js:14567)
at angular.js:14583
at Scope.$get.Scope.$eval (angular.js:15846)
at Scope.$get.Scope.$digest (angular.js:15657)
at Scope.$get.Scope.$apply (angular.js:15951)
at done (angular.js:10364)
at completeRequest (angular.js:10536)
```

Comment: what version of angular? Did you see last answer in your link? Did you try the solutions provided in other answers?

Comment: I'm using  AngularJS v1.4.3 and i just tried other answers, getting error: XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://ip-api.com/json. Request header field x-access-token is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers.

Answer (score 1):

"transformRequest" does not work the same way to remove headers for individual requests past angularjs 1.4 release  .From the documentation its clear that we should be using "headers" instead 
eg:

```
  $http({method: 'GET', 
               url: "url", 
               headers: {
                   'header-name': undefined
                 }
        }).success(function(data){console.log(data)});
```

---

Answer (score 0):

The `$http` service config object allows you to override the http header send for a specific request. See config property headers.

To explicitly remove a header automatically added via `$httpProvider.defaults.headers` on a per request basis, Use the headers property, setting the desired header to undefined.

**NOTE:** Set the desire header/headers to undefined like this, then it will not affect the global settings.

See example:

```
var req = {
 method: 'POST',
 url: 'http://example.com',
 headers: {
   'Content-Type': undefined
 },
 data: { test: 'test' }
}

$http(req).then(function(){...}, function(){...});
```

See more [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http).

This can take a list of headers or a function that return a list of headers. So for the non auth header request make a copy of the default headers remove the header you don't require and then make the request.

Hope this help well.