# Angularjs HTTP interceptors exceptions

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-http

I'm using angularjs HTTP interceptors to intercept all my calls to the back-end, is it possible to give some exceptions to some specific HTTP calls? I've been on Google for the past 2 days and can't find any answers.

Comment: Most likely yes. You need to provide a lot more specific details though for anyone to help

Comment: what do you mean under exception? is it about `try ... catch ...` and `throw`? or is about need to avoid interceptor applied for some particular request?

Comment: if it's about second variant I suggest try searching for "[angularjs] skip interceptor". there are a lot of existing answer

Comment: @skyboyer i saw the answer.
Anyone in need of answer go to (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37649273/how-to-skip-angularjs-interceptor-for-an-http-request)