# $http unset default header

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http

I have interceptor service to add a header to all my requests. However occasionally I don't need this header, so following Angular's documentation I set it to `undefined`:

```
$http({
    url: 'https://hooks.slack.com/services/',
    method: 'POST',
    data: {test: 'test message'},
    headers: {
        'my-header': undefined
    }
})
```

But I still get `Request header field my-header is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response`

What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE**:
I tried setting headers to {}, I tried setting `Content-type` to `text/plain` and `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` which shouldn't be triggering the preflight. But apparently because of custom headers which is what `my-header` is the pre-flight is still issued.

Comment: leave headers empty, don't put my-header in it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set defaults header on AngularJS but don't use it on one specific request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23696202/set-defaults-header-on-angularjs-but-dont-use-it-on-one-specific-request)