# Angular JSON $http request do not send JSON like jQuery

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have read about AngularJS post request header which is `application/json`

But I want to change it to:

```
Content-Type=application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
```

I do the following but the post request is still sent with the same `application/json`

Here is the Angular:

```
 $http.post("server.php", checkUserPostData, 
{"headers" : "Content-Type=application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8"})

            .success(function(data, status, header, config){
                if(data=='exists')
                return true;
                else return false;
            });
```

How should I set the config header of the request then?

Comment: possible duplicate of [AngularJS - Any way for $http.post to send request parameters instead of JSON?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12190166/angularjs-any-way-for-http-post-to-send-request-parameters-instead-of-json)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The headers need to be a JSON object.

Try:

```
{"headers" : { "Content-Type" : "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8" }}
```

From here:
[https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24http)

> headers – {Object} – Map of strings or functions which return strings representing HTTP headers to send to the server. If the return value of a function is null, the header will not be sent.