# How can I keep $http from sending my data as a string with quotes?

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I'm trying to use an Angular $http POST call to an OAuth token service, and I'm having trouble getting the data format correct.

Right now I'm using the following to paramaterize a simple object, like so:

```
$.param({
        grant_type: "password",
        username: 'myusername',
        password: 'mypassword'
    })
```

This produces: **grant_type=password&username=myusername&password=mypassword**

This output is correct.  I need this string, without quotes, to be sent to the server.

I'm using:

```
$http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: '/services/token',
        data: $.param({
            grant_type: "password",
            username: 'myusername',
            password: 'mypassword'
        }),
        headers: {
            'Content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        }
    }).success(function(data) {
        $window.alert(data.access_token);
    }).error(function(data) {
        $window.alert('failed');
    });
```

This produces 400 error on the server because the data sent is: **"grant_type=password&username=myusername&password=mypassword"** (with quotes)

How can I remove the quotes?

Comment: JSON.parse will do it

Comment: simply try data: {
            grant_type: 'password',
            username: 'myusername',
            password: 'mypassword'
        }

Comment: Thank you, but using the object instead causes it to be serialized to a JSON string, which is not the same as x-www-form-urlencoded.  It would produce: `{"grant_type":"password","username":"myusername","password":"mypassword"}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Angular's $http has a default request transform that serializes the data to json which adds the quotes. So just override the transformRequest function. You can do that globally as well, see the link below.

```
var transform = function(data){
    return $.param(data);
}

$http.post("/services/token", {
        grant_type: "password",
        username: 'myusername',
        password: 'mypassword'
    }, {
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'},
    transformRequest: transform
});
```

This question is actually a duplicate: [AngularJS - Any way for $http.post to send request parameters instead of JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12190166/angularjs-any-way-for-http-post-to-send-request-parameters-instead-of-json)

Comment: Ah, I see.  Thanks for the information. I was halfway there, but this makes it clearer.

Answer (score 2):

After some additional digging I came across another similar question.  I like this answer because it's simple, localized, and does not have a jQuery dependency.

[How can I make angular.js post data as form data instead of a request payload?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11442632/how-can-i-make-angular-js-post-data-as-form-data-instead-of-a-request-payload)

This works:

```
$http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: '/services/token',
    data: {
        grant_type: "password",
        username: 'myusername',
        password: 'mypassword'
    }),
    headers: {
        'Content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    },
    transformRequest: function (obj) {
            var str = [];
            for (var p in obj)
                str.push(encodeURIComponent(p) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(obj[p]));
            return str.join("&");
        }
}).success(function(data) {
    $window.alert(data.access_token);
}).error(function(data) {
    $window.alert('failed');
});
```

It's also worth noting that I'm using ASP.Net Web Api's OAuthTokenProvider.  It does not recognize different content types, which is atypical in Web Api because controllers do.