# Angularjs make post request to server with key value pair

Tags: angularjs, post, key-value

I am so beginner programming with Angularjs and I want to make post request to my server. On the server side I'am waiting data with key value pair. But when I try to post with the example code below I sent data in json so ı can't parse it on the server side. I googled this issue but i couldn't find the answer but I'm pretty sure there is a way. I hope somebody will tell this.

```
$scope.postData = function postData(data) {
        $http.post('apiurl/functionName', {post_data:data}).success(
                alert("Success"));
    };
```

Comment: What is your server-side language?

Comment: possible duplicate of [AngularJS - Any way for $http.post to send request parameters instead of JSON?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12190166/angularjs-any-way-for-http-post-to-send-request-parameters-instead-of-json)

Comment: I use php on the server side on the client side i'am sending json data with key value and on the server side i'am decoding and parsing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var request = {};
request.method = 'POST';
request.data = JSON.stringify(JSONdata);
request.url = url;
request.timeout = 1000 * 60;

var promise = $http(request);

promise.success(function(data, status, header, config) {
    //  successCallback;
});

promise.error(function(data, status, header, config) {
    // errorCallback
});
```

Comment: hi Hardy, thak you for your response. i got posting data and parse it successfully with your code. but i got all values as '0'. do you have an idea about this situation?