# Run a hook before $resource constructs the url?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ngresource, angularjs-resource, angularjs-http

I want to programatically alter route parameters *before* $resource constructs the url. I cannot use angular's http interceptor to do this, since the route is already concatenated at that point.

Given an **Assortment.model.js**

```
module.exports = function($resource) {
    return $resource("", {}, {
        get: {
            url: "/assortment/:model/:id",
            method: "GET",
            params: {id: "@id", model: "@model"} //< this needs to be uppercase
        }
    });
};
```

...and some **controller.js**

```
["Supplier", function(Supplier) {
    Supplier.Assortment.get({ id: 5, model: "user" })
}]
```

How can I enforce a hook that will always convert `{model: "user"}` to `{model: "User"}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say that you should go for `tranformRequest` over the `$resource` get part.

**Code**

```
module.exports = function($resource) {
  return $resource("", {}, {
    get: {
      url: "/assortment/:model/:id",
      method: "GET",
      params: {
        id: "@id",
        model: "@model"
      },
      transformRequest: function(data, headers) {
        //here you could have the transformation of parameters
        console.log(data);
        return data;
      },
    }
  });
};
```

Reference [**answer here**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12191613/2435473) but you should keep the transform request part in $resource's `get`.

Comment: Actually angular docs say you can pass a function to each value specified in the `params` object, I think that is definitely suitable. In my `$resource` config files I don't actually pass any data so transformRequest can't really do anything.