# How to convert string of objects to JSON object in angular transformRequest

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, angular-resource

So I'm receiving this string:

```
{"id":"0-worfebvjyyvqjjor","size":17,"price":921,"face":"( .-.)","date":"Mon Jan 04 2016 22:55:30 GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time)"}
{"id":"1-ifma3yxxccgzaor","size":19,"price":98,"face":"( .o.)","date":"Fri Jan 08 2016 16:11:25 GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time)"}
{"id":"2-sa3iurvt4hv0lik9","size":14,"price":659,"face":"( `·´ )","date":"Sun Jan 03 2016 06:20:28 GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time)"}
{"id":"3-bc3tf55q9vx11yvi","size":33,"price":361,"face":"( ° ͜ ʖ °)","date":"Fri Jan 01 2016 22:49:22 GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time)"}
```

here in console.log(data):

```
var WareHouseResource = $resource('/api/products?limit=10', {}, {
    query: {
        method: 'GET',
        isArray: false,
        transformResponse: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    }
});
```

How do I convert data into a JSON array?? I already tried JSON.parse(data) but it throws an error.

Comment: Looks like you're missing comas after each object

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AngularJS - Any way for $http.post to send request parameters instead of JSON?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12190166/angularjs-any-way-for-http-post-to-send-request-parameters-instead-of-json)

Comment: send proper json in the first place. Fix your back end

Comment: It's an exercise, and I was told to not change the backend

Comment: Unless you have correct JSON, you are not going to be success here . Tell whomever that your api is wrong . As @charlietfl said correct you api first. For the question asked here answer is "angular.fromJson()"

Comment: Then do it yourself and stop getting people here to do your homework for you. It doesn't appear you made any effort at all to solve this yourself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the data as an array, you might wanna set `isArray` to `true`

```
var WareHouseResource = $resource('/api/products?limit=10', {}, {
    query: {
        method: 'GET',
        isArray: true
    }
});
```

This is assuming that the string representation you receive is in valid format. I can see that `,` is missing after each object. Is this expected? If yes, you might want to replace `}` with `},`, wrap them in '[]' and then do `angular.fromJson(data)` in the transformer.

Here's a plunker that does just that: https://plnkr.co/edit/ZGLK7PTclapVNwuIlM1T?p=preview

Comment: already tried, it doesn't work :x, I get an unexpected token { error

Comment: @FredericoJesus , try the plunker

Comment: I still get an error, here's my code can you please take a look?
https://github.com/fredericojesus/ascii-warehouse

lib folder is the api, static is the client

Comment: It's the replace I think that it's not working, the second one

Comment: NICE. I solved it with .replace(',\n]', ']'); Thanks dude! It had an enter as a last character

Comment: Well, I'll be stabbing in the dark without actually being able to run the code against the backend but if it's the replace, It could be something to do with `<spaces>`, so, try this as replace `data = ('[' + data + ']').replace(/(\s*)}/g, '},').replace(/(\s*),(\s*)]/, ']');`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use angular.fromJson(). So

```
var WareHouseResource = $resource('/api/products?limit=10', {}, {
    query: {
        method: 'GET',
        isArray: false,
        transformResponse: function(data) {
            console.log(angular.fromJson(data));
        }
    }
});
```

Check out https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.fromJson

```js
var items=[{"id":"0-worfebvjyyvqjjor","size":17,"price":921,"face":"( .-.)","date":"Mon Jan 04 2016 22:55:30 GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time)"},
{"id":"1-ifma3yxxccgzaor","size":19,"price":98,"face":"( .o.)","date":"Fri Jan 08 2016 16:11:25 GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time)"},
{"id":"2-sa3iurvt4hv0lik9","size":14,"price":659,"face":"( `·´ )","date":"Sun Jan 03 2016 06:20:28 GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time)"},
{"id":"3-bc3tf55q9vx11yvi","size":33,"price":361,"face":"( ° ͜ ʖ °)","date":"Fri Jan 01 2016 22:49:22 GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time)"}]

alert(angular.fromJson(items))
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.9/angular.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: already tried, it doesn't work :x, I get an unexpected token { error

Comment: @FredericoJesus Then I hope you are not getting correct JSON String

Comment: @FredericoJesus you are missing commas after each record

Comment: @FredericoJesus I have added snippet , Run Code and you will see it workng

Comment: the thing is, this is an exercise, and I can't change the API. I have to work with that data. what the api return is this:

for (i=0; i<limit; i+=1) {
            res.write(JSON.stringify(createRandomItem(i+skip, sort)) + '\n');
        }
        res.end();