# Angularjs $http.post to contact form 7 with content type application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Tags: angularjs, http, post, contact-form-7, angular-http

I'm successfully sending POST request from chrome postman plug-in to contact-form-7 and I receive mail and everything.
What I can't figure out is how to send same POST request from angular.
Here's what I have in postman:

POST url: http://example.com/be/home/

REQUEST:

```
_wpcf7:4
_wpcf7_version:4.7
_wpcf7_locale:en_US
_wpcf7_unit_tag:wpcf7-f4-p6-o1
fname:john
email:admin@example.com
subject:subject
message:message
_wpcf7_is_ajax_call:1
```

HEADERS:

```
Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Accept:application/json, text/javascript, */*;q=0.01
```

BODY(raw):

```
_wpcf7=4&_wpcf7_version=4.7&_wpcf7_locale=en_US&_wpcf7_unit_tag=wpcf7-f4-p6-o1&fname=john&email=admin@example.com&subject=subject&message=message&_wpcf7_is_ajax_call=1
```

RESPONSE:

```
<textarea>{"mailSent":true,"into":"#wpcf7-f4-p6-o1","captcha":null,"message":"Thank you for your message. It has been sent."}</textarea>
```

Here's what I tried so far:

HomeService:

```
this.sendMessage = function(successCallback, errorCallback){
$http.post('/be/home', {
        headers:{
          'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
          'Accept':'application/json, text/javascript, */*;q=0.01'
        },
        data:{
          '_wpcf7':4,
          '_wpcf7_version':4.7,
          '_wpcf7_locale':'en_US',
          '_wpcf7_unit_tag':'wpcf7-f4-p6-o1',
          'fname':'john',
          'email':'admin@example.com',
          'subject':'subject',
          'message':'message',
          '_wpcf7_is_ajax_call':1
        }
      }).then(function(data){
        successCallback(data);
      }).catch(function(data){
        errorCallback(data);
      });
    }
 }
```

HomeController:

```
HomeService.sendMessage(function(data){
    console.log(data);
}, function(data){
    console.log(data);
}
```

In response I get the whole page, I think I'm sending the headers and data wrong, but I can't figure out how to do it.

EDIT:

`{"_wpcf7":4,"_wpcf7_version":4.7,"_wpcf7_locale":"en_US","_w‌​pcf7_unit...` This is how REQUEST BODY looks like(JSON) I need it to look like this (form data):
 `_wpcf7=4&_wpcf7_version=4.7&_wpcf7_locale=en_US&_wpcf7_unit_‌​tag=wpcf7-f4-p6-o1&f‌​name=john&email=admi‌​n%40example.com&subj‌​ect=subject&message=‌​message&_wpcf7_is_aj‌​ax_call=1` 
And HEADERS: `Content-Type:"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"` 
When I edit request to look like this second example, request passes and email is sent. So question is, is it possible to post Form Data instead of JSON with $http.post?

EDIT:
SOLUTION by @georgeawg

HomeService:

```
this.sendMessage = function(){
    var config = {
        //USE serializer
        transformRequest: $httpParamSerializer,
        headers:{
          'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
          'Accept':'application/json, text/javascript, */*;q=0.01'
        }
     };

     var data = {
          '_wpcf7':4,
          '_wpcf7_version':4.7,
          '_wpcf7_locale':'en_US',
          '_wpcf7_unit_tag':'wpcf7-f4-p6-o1',
          'fname':'john',
          'email':'admin@example.com',
          'subject':'subject',
          'message':'message',
          '_wpcf7_is_ajax_call':1
    };


    //vvvv RETURN httpPromise
    return $http.post('/be/home', data, config);
 };
```

Comment: which type you select for raw body in postman?

Comment: @Gaurav it's Text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To POST data with content type `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, the data needs to be urlencoded. Use the [$httpParamSerializer service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$httpParamSerializer):

```
//this.sendMessage = function(successCallback, errorCallback){    
this.sendMessage = function(){
    var config = {
        //USE serializer
        transformRequest: $httpParamSerializer,
        headers:{
          'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
          'Accept':'application/json, text/javascript, */*;q=0.01'
        }
     };

     var data = {
          '_wpcf7':4,
          '_wpcf7_version':4.7,
          '_wpcf7_locale':'en_US',
          '_wpcf7_unit_tag':'wpcf7-f4-p6-o1',
          'fname':'john',
          'email':'admin@example.com',
          'subject':'subject',
          'message':'message',
          '_wpcf7_is_ajax_call':1
    };


    //vvvv RETURN httpPromise
    return $http.post('/be/home', data, config);
 };
```

The `@` in the email needs to be [percent encoded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding). The param serializer will do that properly.

Also the is no need to use success and error callbacks as the $http service already returns a promise.

See [Why are Callbacks from Promise `.then` Methods an Anti-Pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35660881/why-are-callbacks-from-promise-then-methods-an-anti-pattern).

Comment: It's still sending JSON and response is the whole page.

Answer (score 0):

In the headers, you specify `'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'` while you provide value in a JSON format in the `data` property :

```
    data:{
      '_wpcf7':4,
      '_wpcf7_version':4.7,
      '_wpcf7_locale':'en_US',
      '_wpcf7_unit_tag':'wpcf7-f4-p6-o1',
      'fname':'john',
      'email':'admin@example.com',
      'subject':'subject',
      'message':'message',
      '_wpcf7_is_ajax_call':1
    }
```

Either don't specify `'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'` in order to transmit value with the `"application/json"` content-type that is used by default or else if you really need to use the `'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'` Content-Type, provide in the `data` property a string conform to what `'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'` expects to, that is `_wpcf7=4&_wpcf7_versio=4.7...` .

Comment: I've tried changing data to 
`data:"_wpcf7=4&_wpcf7_version=4.7&_wpcf7_locale=en_US&_wpcf7_unit_tag=wpcf7-f4-p6-o1&fname=john&email=admin@example.com&subject=subject&message=message&_wpcf7_is_ajax_call=1"`
Still getting the same thing, I think that content-type needs to stay application/x-www-form-urlencoded because that is what php is expecting.

Answer (score 0):

Try this without adding the `headers` in request, see this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12190166/angularjs-any-way-for-http-post-to-send-request-parameters-instead-of-json)

**HomeService:**

```
this.sendMessage = function(successCallback, errorCallback) {
    var data = {
        '_wpcf7': 4,
        '_wpcf7_version': 4.7,
        '_wpcf7_locale': 'en_US',
        '_wpcf7_unit_tag': 'wpcf7-f4-p6-o1',
        'fname': 'john',
        'email': 'admin@example.com',
        'subject': 'subject',
        'message': 'message',
        '_wpcf7_is_ajax_call': 1
    }
    return $http.post('/be/home', $.param(data));
}
```

HomeController:

```
HomeService.sendMessage().then(function(data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

Comment: If using the AngularJS default content type, there is no need to stringify as the $http service will do that automatically.

Comment: yes no need of stringify but required to update from object to param string

Comment: The link you quote is old. AngularJS now has the [$httpParamSerializer service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$httpParamSerializer) and there is no need to add jQuery to serialize with `$.param`.