# POST variables not seen in Symfony's 3.2 Controller

Tags: php, rest, symfony

Debugger shows, that **there is** POST data in request, but I cannot get it by `$request->get('foo');`

And `$request->request->all();` gives array `[0]`.

My Ajax POST request (by AngularJS):

```
...
    $http.post('http://admin/about-company/setJSONObj',
        {foo: 'bar'}
    );
```

My controller with debugging info in comments (Symfony 3.2.9):

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
    ...
    public function updateAction(Request $request)
        {
             $foo = $request->get('foo'); // null
             $requestType = $request->getContentType(); // json
             $content = $request->getContent(); // {"foo":"bar"}
```

I used these approach on Symfony 2.7 project, and it worked fine, but I'm not sure, what's happening in these case?

Also, maybe there is any Symfony framework config variable that tells not to parse POST data, or hides it during caching the request?

Comment: did you try $request->request->get('foo');

Comment: I don't know about pre 2.8 (started late) but see [symfony-request-object](http://symfony.com/doc/current/introduction/http_fundamentals.html#symfony-request-object)

Comment: Thanks guys, seems I tried all such variants and not worked. I think soon I'll parce json from $content to roughly fix this )))

Comment: Have you passed a proper _Content-Type_ header?

Comment: @eRIZ, nope, I think AngularJS cares about headers. By the way it sends Content-Type:application/json;charset=UTF-8

Comment: if you are using Angular, please check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12190166/angularjs-any-way-for-http-post-to-send-request-parameters-instead-of-json).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out, my mistake was to expect POST variables in `$request->request->all();` while posting JSON: see explanation  [https://www.toptal.com/...](https://www.toptal.com/php/10-most-common-mistakes-php-programmers-make#common-mistake-7-assuming-post-will-always-contain-your-post-data).

For creating REST api with Symfony it's normal to use FOSRestBundle: see [body listener](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/FOSRestBundle/3-listener-support.html#body-listener). So, it solves my problem in elegant way.

Also, @henrily suggested a [workaroud](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44329012/1915723) somebody can use, but it's just a workaround.

Answer (score 1):

For POST request is:

```
$request->request->get('foo');
```

Comment: Try to dump all the data in the request using `$request->request->all();`.

Comment: it gave me array [0]

Comment: Can you post your javascript code and your definitions of routes too?

Comment: For details: I'm using KunstmaanCMS, and in admin page created angular app (to update some general data using Ajax and not to build heavy interface with forms and other stuff)

Comment: My advice is to use a tool like [postman](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop) to send post request to your controller. Don't forget to add `Content-Type: application/json` to yout header).

Answer (score 0):

Try using FormData for your client-side ajax's call

For example : try something like

```
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append('foo', 'bar')

  $http.post('http://url',
       formData
  );
```

---

Ok, I wasn't paying attention that you used json so,
You wont get the content of $foo in request but you need to json_decode the `$content`

So by keeping the same way you sent data :

> ```
> $http.post('http://admin/about-company/setJSONObj',
>     {foo: 'bar'}
> );
> ```

You just have to call

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Method;
    ...
    /**
    * @Route("/setJSONObj", name="admin_pages_set_ajax_obj")
    * @Method("POST")
    */
    public function updateAction(Request $request)
        {
             $foo = $request->get('foo'); // null
             $requestType = $request->getContentType(); // json
             $content = $request->getContent(); // {"foo":"bar"}
             $data = json_decode($content, true);
             dump($data['foo']); // "foo"
             //And you can know replace the data of the request. So
             $request->request->replace($data);
```

My guess is because symfony need have the `'Content-Type'` `'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'` but Angular by default have a `application/json` (so you can override the headers on the `$http.post` call.

Comment: The same, except $content = `------WebKitFormBoundaryHLFYNZeven585hAi
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="foo"

bar
------WebKitFormBoundaryHLFYNZeven585hAi--`

Comment: thanks for variant, but things was already like you suggesting: 'json application-type' header sets AngularJS for request, and Symfony don't handle it

Comment: json_decode - yes, it should work, but I'll use if not find better solution )

Comment: have you tried to change the header to `'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'` and use `new FormData()` ? This one should work

Comment: yes, it changed $type = `form`, `...request->all()` gives same result as `$content` in 1st comment, but `...->get('foo')` gives `null`...